# Sending raw email header with SwiftMailer

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer, email-headers

What I want is to send raw header using SwiftMailer

Currently this is what I can do with SwiftMailer

```
// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject("This email is sent using Swift Mailer");
$message->setBody("You {fullname}, are our best client ever thanks " .
    " to the {transactions} transactions you made with us.");
$message->setFrom("account@bank.com", "Your bank");
```

Using `$message->setFrom()` I can set the From field in the header but what I want is something like this

```
$rawHeader = 'MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="_=_swift_v4_1467746603_bb0677c43b2ba275b8602c907ef7228a_=_"
List-Unsubscribe: <http://go.proctorgallagher.com/unsubscribe/u/45802/41c5731bb75f7959e5880279725cb9b7b4f8996214976c36a0f93e36e88e7705/876424750>
X-Report-Abuse-To: abuse@pd25.com
x-job: 7215816_12853

--_=_swift_v4_1467746603_bb0677c43b2ba275b8602c907ef7228a_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable'

$message->rawHeader($rawHeader);
```

Or something where I don't have to let the swiftmailer know that `Content-Type` is field and value is `text/plain`

I mean whatever I put get sent as it is don't have to put everything separately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$message->setBody("You {fullname}, are our best client ever thanks " .
    " to the {transactions} transactions you made with us.", "text/plain", "utf-8");
```

Comment: With this solution I would have to add the content separately again - what I want is put header in one place and be done with that - if it's possible